# sonar-project.properties usage in Gitlab CI

Tags: java, gitlab-ci, maven-3, pipeline, sonarqube-scan

This is not specific question, just wanted to share my workaround since didn't found any solutions here before.

Task: migration from Jenkins to Gitlab CI with Sonar integration
What we have there: Maven project
What does official documentation says:

```
sonarqube-check:
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"  # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"  # Tells git to fetch all the branches of the project, required by the analysis task
  cache:
    key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
    paths:
      - .sonar/cache
  script:
    - mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true
  allow_failure: true
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master # or the name of your main branch
    - develop
```

Problem: in Jenkins we use sonar-project.properties, but those aren't picked-up by Gitlab-ci by default, -Dsonar.properties=$CI_PROJECT/sonar-project.properties didn't solved the case and my team wanted to keep that document, 'cos it is easier to update than long line in pipeline.
And I found out (and tested just in case) mvn sonar:sonar gets its configurations from the command line (with -Dsonar.x=y parameters) and the pom. It does not read sonar-project.properties.

Why we don't use pom.xml -> well, migration can take and it must be less painless for developers + at this point we are using Jenkins+BitBucket and Gitlab in parallel with mirroring, so might be in future we probably will end-up with updating poms.

MY QUICK FIX:
I have wrote basic script with "sed" commands to extract -Dsonar.* descriptions to variable, which was added to pipelines command.

```
sonar:
  stage: validate
  image: maven:3-jdk-11
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
    GIT_DEPTH: "1"  # Tells git to fetch specific branch 
    SONAR_HOST_URL: http://<sub>your url</sub>
  before_script:
    - sed -e 's|^| -D|g' sonar-project.properties | grep "sonar." >> props.txt //exports only line with sonar.<setting> and write it in new file with -Dsonar.<setting>
    - sed -i '/-D#/d' props.txt // removed in case setting is commented out
    - sed -i '/-Dm/d' props.txt // removed lines that does not go with specifications(in my case that was module description)*
    - sed -i '/-Dsonar.modules/d' props.txt // removed modules *'cos it gave error with folder name duplication on Sonar Scan 
    - export SONAR_PROPS=$(sed 's/["\n\r]//g' props.txt) // exported that file to single-line variable
    - rm -rf props.txt
  script:
    - echo $SONAR_PROPS
    # - mvn verify <here-I-have-my-mvn-project-setting> sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_LOGIN -Dsonar.password=$SONAR_PASSWORD  $SONAR_PROPS
  allow_failure: true
  when: manual
```

This was my quick fix for using sonar-project.properties in mvn command. Uses same files as Jenkins.

Comment: This solution will not work properly if you have module settings, 'cos -Dsonar.module=X,Z doesn't works, by default it will pick-up X, Y and Z module. Working on this solution.